# Make certificate signed after installing it as unsigned

Tags: java-me, symbian

Is there is a way in nokia symbian to make it signed manually on device after installing it as unsigned or before installing.

With self signed method or any other method.

Comment: Read this link [Java_ME_signing_for_dummies](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_signing_for_dummies)

Answer (score 0):

For the Above purpose you need to buy a Singing Certificate from VeriSign or other Trusted site. My Company has purchased same certificate worth Rs 20K. It is onetime payment. however you can have your own customized certificate called self signed certificates. Just google it how to make self signed certificate. It will show you the stesp for it. After signing with that certificate, you need to install that certificate on the same phone. It has benefit that , this works like a licencing of your own Application.